# Why do bcc: recipients show up in the headers?

Tags: email

I just noticed that anytime there is a bcc: recipient from a CiviCRM-generated email, the bcc: line shows up in the headers as though it was a regular cc: -- why is this?

[image: bcc shows up]

**Edit:** It looks like this was a known issue at one point so maybe just never fully fixed, or a regression?

- https://forum.civicrm.org/?topic=16686
- https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7355